# GSON - java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, gson

I am using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library to convert my Java Object to JSON. While using the below code , I got

> Method threw 'java.lang.ClassCastException' exception.
>   java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String

```
gson.toJson(MyObject)
```

Is there any way of finding out for which field/variable/attribute in the class  it failed  ?

Comment: What is the class of `MyObject`?

Comment: It's one of our Custom user defined Class file. You can assume say MyClass.java